# AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters setVolume atTime not working only with kCMTimeZero

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer

Im am developing an iOS app in Xcode. I am still new to programming. 
I am trying to set the volume of an audiotrack while playing it with an `AVPlayer`. It is working great if a set the time at `kCMTimeZero` but I want it to set the volume one second after the button was pressed.

***Not* working**

```
- (IBAction)maxVolButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [audioInputParams1 setVolume:1 atTime:time1];
    [self applyAudioMix];
}
```

**Working**

```
- (IBAction)minVolButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [audioInputParams1 setVolume:0 atTime:kCMTimeZero];
    [self applyAudioMix];
}
```

What should I write after `atTime` if I want a one second delay?

ANSWER: 
Ok so I figured it out. You have to add the time where the current item is at the moment. I use setVolumeRampFromStartVolume with a very little time interval instead of setVolume. setVolume fades to the given volume for some reason I haven't figured it out why. 
It works for me like this:

```
CMTime time1 = CMTimeMake(1000, 1000); //2s
CMTime time2 = CMTimeMake(1001, 1000); //3s
CMTime timeCurrent = [player currentTime];
CMTime time1Added = CMTimeAdd(timeCurrent, time1);
CMTime time2Added = CMTimeAdd(timeCurrent, time2);
CMTimeRange fadeInTimeRange = CMTimeRangeFromTimeToTime(time1Added, time2Added);
[audioInputParams1 setVolumeRampFromStartVolume:0 toEndVolume:1 timeRange:fadeInTimeRange];
[self applyAudioMix];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something like this:

```
- (IBAction)maxVolButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(setVolume:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

- (void)setVolume:(id)sender{
    [audioInputParams1 setVolume:1 atTime:kCMTimeZero];
    [self applyAudioMix];
}
```

In first method you are saying: wait for 1 second and then call method setVolume:.

Comment: Yes i thought of that but I just cant explaing why it isn't workink if I put for example: CMTime time1 = CMTimeMake(1000, 1000); instead of  kCMTimeZero.